# How can I use the Callback result in WCF?

Tags: wcf, callback, publish-subscribe

I am new to WCF, and now designing a service with Pub/Sub using callback. I have this stupid question: how can I make use of the callback? Let's say I have the callback interface called ICallback, with one function called ProcessResult(). And I have an implementation class called MyCallback. Then in my client side, I can initialize it like this:

```
Dim cb As ICallback = New MyCallback()
Dim MyClient = New MyServiceClient(New InstanceContext(cb))
```

The class MyServiceClient is generated using svcutil.exe. Now whenever the WCF server gets information the client is interested in, it will call the callback function ProcessResult(). All the online examples I found online, for simplicity, just output a line inside the callback function. But in real life I need to pass this information out of the MyCallback class. This is where I lost: since on my client side, my objects are only using the funcitons of the object MyClient, not the cb, how can I implement the ProcessResult() function, so that the client objects can be aware of the fact that this function is called? I can for example raise an event, which is declared in the MyCallback class, inside this function, but since the client side objects don't have a reference to the cb, how can Ｉ make any event handler to handle it？

Answer (score 0):

svcutil has an option  `/async` which allow you to generate also async method calls. Isn't it help you?